# webView decidePolicyFor getting triggered by request with URL "about:blank"

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm working on [EasyBrowser Challenge](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/4/6/wrap-up) by Hacking With Swift, where the first part of challenge states "If users try to visit a URL that isn’t allowed, show an alert saying it’s blocked."

I placed an alertController and action inside the `webView decidePolicyFor` method to get triggered by an unapproved host (shown below), but on app startup this gets triggered by a request with URL "about:blank". There appear to be two navigation requests where the first one is the expected/approved site (apple.com in this case) and the second is the "about:blank" where it triggers the alert action. Why is this happening even though the startup request has an approved url and I am not triggering a reload on startup?

Full code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/yanichik/UIKit_HackingWithSwift/tree/main/project4%3A%20WKWebView/WKWebView/WKWebView)

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let url = navigationAction.request.url
    
    if let host = url?.host{
        print(host)
        for website in websites {
            if host.contains(website){
                decisionHandler(.allow)
                return
            }
        }
    }
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Access Blocked!", message: "Website you are trying to access is blocked. Please request access.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go back.", style: .cancel))
    present(alertController, animated: true)
    print("not allowed")
    decisionHandler(.cancel)
}
```

Comment: Because you don't consider all possible cases with URL scheme and host?

Comment: That's just how `WKWebView` is. The first request is always about:blank. How about disabling the alert until the request to the initial website is sent?

Comment: @Sweeper I changed url to take from mainDocumentURL `let url = navigationAction.request.mainDocumentURL` and this seems to work. I've been getting the about:blank as the second request.